# Use of ROC curve

Tags: statistical-significance, effect-size, roc

I have two quantitative data sets (MRI Images), each looking at a different quantitative metric, lets say A and B. I have extracted regions of interest (ROIs) for ~300 regions (exact same region for both groups) in each group A and B. Their histograms just barely overlap, and I have a box and whisker plot to show statistical significance between the two groups A and B.

Is it acceptable to use a ROC curve to help validate the significant difference between A and B (by showing an AUC ~= 1)?